# Package 'jdk' isn't signed with proper key

Tags: jvm, tomcat7

can some one tell what below lines indicates. I am using tomcat7 its *suddenly goes down after some time . i can see below log in /var/log/messages file. is jvm got crashed ?*

```
Dec 28 17:39:06 track03 abrt[23595]: Saved core dump of pid 9849 (/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-12-28-17:38:14-9849 (12624896000 bytes)    
Dec 28 17:39:06 track03 abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2016-12-28-17:38:14-9849' creation detected    
Dec 28 17:39:07 track03 abrtd: Package 'jdk' isn't signed with proper key    
Dec 28 17:39:07 track03 abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-12-28-17:38:14-9849' exited with 1    
Dec 28 17:39:07 track03 abrtd: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-12-28-17:38:14-9849'
```

Answer (score 1):

That means process `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java` crashed and core dump was saved to directory `/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-12-28-17:38:14-9849`. But `abrtd` daemon recognized that package `jdk` was not signed with GPG key so directory was deleted.

For some more information check:

[ABRT logs messages with "Package  isn't signed with proper key."](https://support.zend.com/hc/en-us/articles/203782516-ABRT-logs-messages-with-Package-packagename-isn-t-signed-with-proper-key-)

[Red Hat Linux error - Package 'rmmagent' isn't signed with proper key](https://support.solarwindsmsp.com/kb/msp_rmm_(saas)/000019000)

If you want to inspect core dumps you can change default behavior of abrtd in case of third-party packages:

1. Edit the file `/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf`
2. Set `OpenGPGCheck = no`
3. Reload `abrtd` with the command: `service abrtd reload`